# Can't get a function to work

Tags: python, function

I am try to create a function that will end my game with a message counting down until it ends, and I am having to repeat this block of code a lot in my text adventure game, so I decided to make a function of it for the sake of neatness, and efficiency. But I cannot figure out how to define and call such a function. This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
print "That\'s a real shame..."
time.sleep(1)
print 'Exiting program in 5 seconds:'
time.sleep(1)
print '5'
time.sleep(1)
print '4'
time.sleep(1)
print '3'
time.sleep(1)
print '2'
time.sleep(1)
print '1'
time.sleep(1)
sys.exit('Exiting Game...')
break
```

So I defining the function like this:

```
def exit():
    print "That\'s a real shame..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'Exiting program in 5 seconds:'
    time.sleep(1)
    print '5'
    time.sleep(1)
    print '4'
    time.sleep(1)
    print '3'
    time.sleep(1)
    print '2'
    time.sleep(1)
    print '1'
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.exit('Exiting Game...')
    break
```

And I am calling the function like this:

```
elif ready == 'n':
    exit
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: exit change to exit()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would call the function by typing `exit()`. I modified your countdown code and turned it into a function that I called inside `exit()` to demonstrate how to call one function from piece of code.

```
def exit():
    print "That\'s a real shame..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'Exiting program in 5 seconds:'
    time.sleep(1)
    count_down(5) # Call Countdown clock
    print 'Exiting Game...'
    sys.exit()

def count_down(number):
    for i in reversed(range(number)):
        print i+1
        time.sleep(1)

exit() # <-- This how you call exit, you were missing the parentheses at the end.
```

Output:

```
That's a real shame...
Exiting program in 5 seconds:
5
4
3
2
1
Exiting Game...
```

**Edit:** *Added more in-depth explanation.*

The first line`def count_down` is a function that takes one [parameter](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) and has one purpose, to handle the count down.

```
def count_down(number):
```

The second row contains what we call a [for loop](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). The purpose of this code is to loop through objects. Starting from `4` then `3,2,1` etc. And the variable `i` at the same row will change for each time the loop goes through a number and is accessible only inside the loop. The first time print is executed it will be 5, then the next time 4 and so on.

```
 for i in reversed(range(number)):
```

In this function we also use two additional keywords and one parameter, `reversed`, `range` and the parameter `number`.

```
reversed(range(number))
```

[range](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html) is used to create a list of numbers e.g. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, that the for statement will loop through starting with `0`, then it takes the next number all the way until it reaches the last number `4`. I will explain why it starts at zero and only goes to four, and not five at the end of my answer.

[reversed](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) is used to reverse the list we created with range. Since we want to start at `4`, and not `0`.

Before `reversed` => `[0,1,2,3,4]`

After `reversed]` => `[4,3,2,1,0]`

`number` is a parameter. A parameter is a value that we provide when we execute the function from your `exit()` function by including a value inside the parentheses `()`. In this case we specified 5, so the list we created with 
`range` will range from 0 - 4 (0,1,2,3,4 = five numbers in total). If you instead specified 10 within the parentheses it would create a list starting from 0 all the way to 9. And your code would count down from 10 to 1, instead of from 5 to 1.

When Python has started working on the `for loop` it will execute the code inside, starting with `print` and then `sleep`, and continues to do so for for each number in the list created by `range`. Since we specified five in this case, it will execute the code a total of five times.

As Python is executing the code within the `for loop` it will first call the print function. Because the for loop will start at `4`, not `5`, we need to do some basic arithmetics and increase the value of each item we loop through by one. We do this by typing `+ 1` after our variable `i`.

The reason why it starts at 4 and not 5 is because in programming lists starts with the number `0`, and not `1`. There  is a more technical explanation available on the reason why [lists](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/lists.html) start with 0, and not 1 (or 4, and not 5 in this case since we reversed the list) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am very new to python, and programming in general, but could you attempt to explain the count_down function to me? I don't quite understand
for i in reversed(xrange(number)):

Comment: Anything in particular that you need explaining?

Comment: Sure. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @RyanHosford I tried to keep it as basic as possible. Feel free to poke me again if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining that to me, it makes sense to me now

Comment: Sorry to bother you with one last thing, but how would i include a break statement in a function? I am trying to make another function with an if/elif inside it, and i want the if to have a break in it so it breaks out of a while loop. I hope that made sense. Sorry if it didn't

Comment: Take a look at this http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

If that doesn't help open another question and I'll try to answer it when I wake up again tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 4):

You are supposed to call it as `exit()`, not `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.  Use a `tuple` that holds the message and the timer delay so you can even control the delay time for each message.

```py
import time, sys
messages = [
    ("That's a shame", 1),
    ("Exiting program in 5 seconds", 1),
    (None, 5)
]

for k,v in messages:
    if k:
        print(k)
        time.sleep(v)
    else:
        # start countdown timer
        while v:
            print v
            time.sleep(1)
            v -= 1

sys.exit()
```

Answer (score -1):

A good way to do this code is:

```
def exit():
    timer= 5
    print "That\'s a real shame..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'Exiting program in 5 seconds:'
    for i in range (5):
        time.sleep(1)
        print timer
        timer = timer - 1
    sys.exit('Exiting Game...')

##You call the function like this
exit()
```