# collect data by id using javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have to save temporary data for my webpage using java script.This is the way that i save i one by one since the data is an array.

```
var product= new Array();
product[1] = document.getElementById("product[1]").value;
product[2] = document.getElementById("product[2]").value;
```

This method is working. but when i run it by looping, it doesnt work.

```
for(var i=1; i < no_item; i++){
product[i] = document.getElementById("product[i]").value;
}
```

*product[] is a varibale that I take from a html dropdown menu

Can anyone please tell me the problem ? thanks ~ =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be written as, as you are going to be getting the id "product[i]" every time with your original code. This will get "product[1]" then "product[2]" and so on:

```
for(var i=1; i < no_item; i++){
    product.push(document.getElementById("product[" + i + "]").value);
}
```

Also, as a comment, we tend to prefer `var product = [];` over `var product = new Array();` in javascript but both will work.

Comment: thanks, it works.but abit weird.how can i start the array number with 1 and not with 0 ?
another problem is when I use it with php, such as product[1] and product[2]. the value of product[1] is assign to product[2] and product[1] is empty. what is the problem ?

Comment: Is there a good reason to start with 1? You may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c?lq=1

Comment: @user2892997 You can do what you were doing `product[i] = ...` but it will exaggerate the length of the array as product[0] will be set to undefined

Comment: $product=@$_GET['product'];
This is the code for php that i collect the array and use, but the array is not in order to what I want.The value of product[1] is assign to product[2] and product[1] is empty. Can you please guide me on this?

Comment: lets say i key in 1,2,3 as the first three array, when i read the , the array is like this , array1 =1 array2 = , array3 =2 array4 = , array5=3 , the comma is included in the array. how can i solve this ?

Comment: All indexs will be i-1 in an array. You really should not be accessing the values explicitly by index and if you need to store some data about some item in an array I would wrap it in an object - eg: `product.push({id:i, value: document.getElementById("product[" + i + "]").value})

Comment: List (arrays in js are lists) indexs should really not be used for state stuff in (any) language