# Trying to create a minesweeper like game placing random mines with user input using 2d array

Tags: arrays, 2d, minesweeper

Im trying to create a minesweeper like simulation when 0 is clear and X is a mine the user inputs the number of mines and using a random generator places it in the 2D array. When i run it the grid print but i get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 and not sure how to fix it. I have never worked with 2D arrays before.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.Random;

  public class Minesweeper {


          private  static  int count = 0;  /* used to count the number of mines */

         public static void main ( String [] args) {

              int r = 12;
              int c = 12;
              int ground [][] = new int [r][c]; //2D array 12 x 12 
              int a = 0;  // variable to print 0's as an integer instead of a string 


                    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); // scanner for the user to input number of mines 

        System.out.print("Enter mines: ");
        Random myRandom = new Random();
        int N; // N is the variable for the number of mines 
        N = sc.nextInt(); // scanner to input the number 

        for (int k = 0; k < ground.length; k++) { // nested loop to print a 12 x 12 grid

             for (int j = 0; j < ground.length; j++) {
               System.out.print(" " + a + " " ); // prints the 0s

          }
                System.out.println();
      }


        while(count <=  N) { // loop to count the mine numbers the user chose
                         /* if count < N, we need to put more mines */


                        do {
                                 r = myRandom.nextInt(12); // generate the mines in random places
                                 c = myRandom.nextInt(12);

                        }   while(mineOrNot(r, c) == false);


                       count += 1;// count to place the right amount of mines 
        }


    }

// function to make sure no 2 mines are in the same location 
        public  static  boolean  mineOrNot(int r, int c) {
            int ground [][] = new int [r][c];
           // if theres no mines its ok to place one 
         if(ground[r][c] == 0) {
             ground[r][c] = 1; // it is ok, put a mine at here 
             return true;
         }
         else 
           return false;
           }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't code in Java, I can only give you the basics of why you're receiving this error. It's basically a right of passage for starting out with arrays, and even experienced programmers run into this issue from time to time in certain cases.

[Array Indexing in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841172/why-is-array-indexing-in-java-start-with-0)

Basically, what's happening is you're attempting to access a part of this array that does not exist within the range you've set for it.

E.G. You're accessing element 13, null, and attempting to use it, causing the error.

Throw a breakpoint in if you can (don't use Java, I imagine Oracle has this functionality) and step through each iteration and try and count exactly the ticks over your array.

It should remain from 0 - 11, since array indexes in Java start at 0.

So your  *1 - 12* cells become index

*0 - 11*.