# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting an exception and i don´t understand why

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = 3;
    int[] numbers = new int[n];
    float total = 0;


    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

        System.out.println("Please type the number " + i + ":");
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();

        total = total + numbers[i];

    }


    System.out.println("The average of the 3 number is: " + total / n);
}
```

Console:

```
Please type the number 1:
3
Please type the number 2:
4
Please type the number 3:
5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at Ejercicio12.main(Ejercicio12.java:17)
```

Comment: Java array indexes are numbered from from 0, and the last index being n-1. In your case numbers[3] => [0,1,2]. You have started your loop from 1 and going to =3. It should be  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

Comment: arrays start with index `0` and go up to `length-1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is array indexing in Java start with 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841172/why-is-array-indexing-in-java-start-with-0)

Comment: Obligatory Dijkstra reference: [Why numbering should start at zero](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)

Comment: What if I get the same exception but my numbering starts at 0? for(int i=0; i<=food.size(); i++ ){
            System.out.println(food.get(i));
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because array index start at 0

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = 3;
int[] numbers = new int[n];
float total = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
int row=i+1;
    System.out.println("Please type the number " + row + ":");
    numbers[i] = input.nextInt();

    total = total + numbers[i];

}

System.out.println("The average of the 3 number is: " + total / n);
}
```

Comment: a trivial question is better answered with comment

Comment: @SharonBenAsher No, please, don't answer in comments - comments are for commenting. However, I'd appreciate if you'd contribute your voice for closing this question as a duplicate - in 10 years of SO, there really should be a duplicate for a "java arrays are 0-based" question.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I voted for closing. however, if there was no duplicate, I believe it is common practice here to answer trivial questions in comments

Comment: @SharonBenAsher *If* there is a way to close the question (e.g. as "trivial typo" / "problem resolved in a way that is unlikely to help anyone else" etc.), then, yes, feel free to leave a comment, sure, why not. I agree that in this particular case, a comment would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes starts from 0. Your length is 3 and your counter variable (`i`) starts from 1.

You can use

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, insert this inside your main method

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = 3;
    int[] numbers = new int[n];
    float total = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        System.out.println("Please type the number " + (i + 1) + ":");
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();

        total = total + numbers[i];

    }


    System.out.println("The average of the 3 number is: " + total / n);
```

Comment: Instead of posting slightly modified code explain what was wrong in the original code and what you changed to make it work (keep in mind what has already been posted in other answers). Currently this answer doesn't provide any value to the thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing error listed below

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3

```
var arr = arrayOf("One","Two","Three")
 println(arr[3])
```

In this Array we just defined three values and index start from 0, So Index 3 doesn't exist in array that's why it's giving this Exception

Try to print index value which includes in Array Such As

```
println(arr[1])
```