# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Tags: java, arrays

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>     at arraydekla.main(arraydekla.java:19)
>   C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

*My code*:

[image: My code]

Comment: Please do **not** post images of your code. Copy-paste the code here, using the proper formatting

Comment: `3` is not a valid index as you've made an array of size two by three, the max index of your inner arrays will be `2` (valid indexes are: `0, 1, 2` for an array of size 3)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java are 0-based.

This means that you start counting indexes from `0`. Thus, an array of size 2 will contain elements at indexes number `0`, and `1`. An array of size 3 will contain elements at indexes `0`, `1`, and `2`.

In your code, you are accessing the element at `[0,3]` on line 19, and `[2, 0]` on line 23. Lines 23 and 27 contain the same type of error.

For more info:

https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arrays.asp

[Why is array indexing in Java start with 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841172/why-is-array-indexing-in-java-start-with-0)

Comment: I also suggest you add the following reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841172/why-is-array-indexing-in-java-start-with-0

Answer (score 0):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown to indicate that an array is accessed with an illegal index. 
Index of an array always starts with zero.

As the array is of size [2][3], we can only access the array elements [0][0], [0][1], [0][2], [1][0], [1][1], [1][2].

We cannot access [2][3], [1][3] as the index is greater than the size of the array.