# JMeter split function Error... invoking bsh method

Tags: function, split, jmeter

````
JMeter test plan has 1 user defined variable Message with a value of <Case Number 000808009 Created.>

1 debug sampler with this BeanShell PostProcessor:

    ``` lang-js
    log.info("Strip out case number");
    log.info("CaseCreated<${Message}>");
    ${__split(${Message},MessagePieces," ")};
    log.info("MessagePieces_3<${MessagePieces_3}>");
    vars.put("CaseNumber", ${MessagePieces_3});
    log.info("CaseNumber<${CaseNumber}>");
    ```


The Debug PostProcessor shows these variables:

Message=Case Number 000808009 Created.
MessagePieces=Case Number 000808009 Created.
MessagePieces_1=Case
MessagePieces_2=Number
MessagePieces_3=000808009
MessagePieces_4=Created.
MessagePieces_n=4

CaseNumber does not appear.

Log shows this:
````

2022-12-30 15:59:23,580 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: Strip out case number
2022-12-30 15:59:23,580 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: CaseCreated<Case Number 000808009 Created.>
2022-12-30 15:59:23,580 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``log.info("Strip out case number"); log.info("CaseCreated<Case Number 000808009 C . . . '' Encountered "000" at line 3, column 13.

2022-12-30 15:59:23,580 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: ``log.info("Strip out case number"); log.info("CaseCreated<Case Number 000808009 C . . . '' Encountered "000" at line 3, column 13.

````
I've tried every syntax I could Google to no avail.  Any thoughts/suggestions?  It seems to get confused with the actual message line as part of the inline evaluation of the beanshell.

I have already found this solution that I can use, but I would prefer to use the split function.

    ``` lang-js
    String line = vars.get("Message");
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    log.info(words[i]);
    if (i == 2) {
    log.info("Third word is: " + words[2]);
    }
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). If you want to extract `000808009` from the User Defined Variable and save it into `CaseNumber` variable you could use the following Groovy code:

   ```
   vars.put('CaseNumber', vars.get('Message').split(' ')[2])
   ```

   Apart from this there are following problems in your script:

   - you're inlining [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) into code which is not something you should be normally doing
   - in Beanshell/Java/Groovy arrays indices are [zero-based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841172/why-does-array-indexing-in-java-start-with-0/24841371#24841371) so 3rd item in the split array will have index of 2

   More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter:
   [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
2. You could also avoid scripting completely and extract the case number using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configured like:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks!  vars.put('CaseNumber', vars.get('Message').split(' ')[2]) worked.  Still don't understand why I shouldn't be able to use the $__split function, but I'm moving on.  Thanks!