# C - Array is out of Range

Tags: c, arrays, range

Considering the following:

```
#define SIZE 5

/* ... */

int oxen[SIZE] = {5,3,2,8};
int yaks[SIZE];
yaks[SIZE] = oxen [SIZE];   /* -->Out of range */
```

Can someone explain why its out of range?

Comment: Yes. For an array of size 5, the valid subscripts (indexes) are 0-4, so there is no `yaks[5]` or `oxen[5]`.

Comment: Because you have not read page one of the "arrays" section in any C book or tutorial.

Comment: @John3136 or any other page either; I'm guessing that he is trying to assign all elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [C is zero-indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c), `oxen[SIZE]` is really trying to deference a sixth element that does not exist. Use the index `[SIZE-1]`, instead.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays indices in C start at 0, so your `oxen` and `yaks` arrays range from `0` to `SIZE-1`.
You're outside the allowed boundaries, as the compiler rightly warns you about.

Answer (score 0):

because c Language can access the elements of array by their indexes 
thus 
index start from 0 to n-1 where n is a number of elements in your array 
so in your case u can access elements from 0 to 4 indexes 
if u deal with array of characters maybe this works because of null terminator '\0'
also u may not get an errors and get random results because its compiler dependent :)