# In C, how does the length in an array definition map to addressing?

Tags: c, arrays

In C, when I define an array like `int someArray[10]`, does that mean that the accessible range of that array is `someArray[0]` to `someArray[9]`?

Comment: that is true my friend

Comment: See also [Why does indexing start with zero in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c) — and there are numerous other related questions too.

Comment: I understood that indexing is 0-based in c, I just didn't understand that an defining an array `...[10]` meant 0...9 and not 0...10 :D

Answer (score 4):

Yes, indexing in [c](/questions/tagged/c) is [zero-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), so for an array of `n` elements, valid indices are `0` through `n-1`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because C's memory addressing is easily computed by an offset

```
myArray[5] = 3
```

roughly translates to

```
store in the address myArray + 5 * sizeof(myArray's base type)
the number 3.
```

Which means that if we permitted

```
myArray[1]
```

to be the first element, we would have to compute

```
store in the address myArray + (5 - 1) * sizeof(myArray's base type)
the number 3
```

which would require an extra computation to subtract the `1` from the `5` and would slow the program down a little bit (as this would require an extra trip through the ALU.

Modern CPUs could be architected around such issues, and modern compilers could compile these differences out; however, when C was crafted they didn't consider it a must-have nicety.

Comment: For one-based indices, there is no extra trip through the MMU. An additional arithmetic operation is required, but no access to memory happens, until the final address has been calculated.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ALU, but I guess my typing "muscle memory" worked against me this time.

Answer (score 1):

Think of an array like this:

```
* 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
                DATA

* = array indices
```

So the the range of access would be [0,9] (inclusive)