# Program crashing with undefined reason?

Tags: c, turbo-c

Here is my simple program. I run it many times. Sometimes it will pop out a warning and break Turbo C. Why? I am using 32bit Windows 7.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(){
int arr[10][10];
int i,j;
clrscr();
    for(i=1;i<11;i++){
        for(j=1;j<11;j++){
        arr[i][j]=i*j;
        printf("%d\t",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c

Comment: that's why one should also run a static analyzer over c code, e.g., http://gimpel-online.com//cgi-bin/genPage.py?srcFile=diy.c&cgiScript=analyseCode.py&title=Do-It-Yourself+Example+%28C%29&intro=This+example+allows+you+to+specify+your+own+C+code.&compilerOption=online32.lnt&includeOption={{quotedIncludeOption}}, complains

Comment: It's not crashing for "undefined reason". It's crashing because you specifically told it to access memory that wasn't yours. C arrays are indexed from 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, the reason is that arrays in c are indexed from `0` to `N - 1`.

So instead of

```
for (i = 1 ; i < 11 ; ++i)
```

it has to be

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
```

because `N` in your case is `10`, and the same for `j` of course.

As you can see it's not **Undefined Reason**, it certainly is undefined behavior, but the reason is a bug in your code, so always blame your code first, it has the highest probability to be the responsible for the unexpected behavior, if you prove that your code works and I mean a mathematical proof kind of proof, then you can blame the compiler or anyone you like.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
arr[i][j]=i*j;
```

`i` and `j` values will range from 1 to 10. However, `ar[10][10]` is actually out of bounds of array.

Since `C` follows 0-based indexing, change this:

```
for(i=1;i<11;i++){
    for(j=1;j<11;j++){
```

to this:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
```