# Why does indexes of lists or tuple start with 0?

Tags: python

Why does indexes of lists or tuple start with 0 ? As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c) in C it is due to pointers. There are no pointers in Python. So, is it related to CPython? Or is it due to some other reason?

Comment: Pretty much every language does it like that. It's standard (because it makes sense in C?). Also see here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm

Comment: Look at [this blog post](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html) from Guido van Rossum (Python's father).

Comment: Because [Dijkstra](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) was often right.

Comment: Not in an answer-ready state but 1+1=2 whereas 0+0=0 if you see where I'm going. I'll try to work that out

Answer (score 2):

It's not just Python.  Most, if not all, programming languages also start indexing at 0.  It makes many things easy and consistent.

Comment: not "all", unless (among others) Pascal is not a programming language anymore :)

Comment: .. hence the term "Most" :-)  Anybody uses Pascal anymore?  I loved it long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it has to with do the CPython implementation. A list object in CPython is represented by the following C structure. ob_item is a list of pointers to the list elements. allocated is the number of slots allocated in memory.

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    PyObject **ob_item;
    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

Take a look at this article describing [python list implementation](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/).

Another good reason behind this decision is slice notation. Take a look at this [article](http://python-history.blogspot.gr/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html) from the author of python.

Answer (score 0):

Answer, pointer arithmetic.

In C and other languages, array members can be accessed by adding the index to the array's memory address. So adding 0 to the address gives the first position, 1 gives the second, etc. Look here:

https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html

So it is the indexing convention because of how the underlying machine code operates.