# python of xlwings, I don't understand one of rule

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I could understand clearly the `rng[0, 0]` and `rng[1]`, but why? Why `rng[:, 3:]` slicing to be `$D$1:$D$5`? And why `rng[1:3, 1:3]` to be `$B$2:$C$3`, I cannot understand the rule of slicing.

```
Range indexing/slicing
Range objects support indexing and slicing, a few examples:

rng = xw.Book().sheets[0].range('A1:D5')
```

Comment: just google it and you will immediately find rules for slicing with numerous examples. http://www.dotnetperls.com/slice-python

Comment: Thank you for your good webside, I'm learning it, thanks again. :)

Comment: Forgot to mention: Don't forget that Python indexing starts with 0 and not 1

Comment: I just overview your web, but I still can't figure out my issue, and I don't know how to search the answer from Google. Would you mind help me figure this question out? Thank you.

Comment: I know some basic rules about python, but I never meet slice way like this rng[1:3, 1:3],  it include ':' and ','

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a go. Because in square brackets, indexing starts at `0` *. So for a 1-based indexing system, consider [1:3, 1:3] as (2:4, 2:4). Also bear in mind that the value after `:` is not included, so inclusively (2:4, 2:4) is (2:3, 2:3). The second Excel Column is B, the third C, and the second Excel row is 2 and the third 3. Hence the range is B2:C3.

IMO a horrible choice of example!

Given a range A1:D5, slicing with rng[:, 3:] means all rows and fourth column to end column, hence D1:D5.

Taking just the column element [1:3] from the same range (A1:D5). The slicing starts (including) the second index element (0 first, 1 second) ie `B` and continues to immediately before the fourth index element (A, B, C, `D`). Hence B:C.

[image: SO39226421 example]

`*` For *why* start at `0` there are details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c).

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking your idea almost 30mins....but still couldn't understand.....is there anyway more clear? Sorry for my bad IQ.....:)

Comment: I got it now!!!! Thank you very much! I thouht it would more clear[1:3,1:3]means[row2 to row 3, column 2 to column 3]

Comment: Thank you pnuts, you helped me lot, I totally understand now :)