# generate random numbers and put them in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, random, dice

I'm looking to write a little dice game called [Farkle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkle) (you may know it from Kingdom come delivarance) in C++ but I'm still learning, so I have some trouble with it. 
atm I'm trying to roll 6 dice and put every rolled number in an array to be able to work with it afterwards. everything seem to work fine but Visual Studio ist outputting this error Code:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'die' was corrupted.

this is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;


void dice() {
    int die[5];
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 6) {
        die[i] = rand() % 6 + 1;
        cout << die[i];
        i++;
    }
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    dice();
    system("STOP");
    return 0;
}
```

is ths actually the right approach for this kind of programm?

Comment: `int die[5]`.What all indices do you think you can access?

Comment: array of size N have index from 0 to N-1, if int die[N] then loop will be (for int i = 0; i< N; i++)

Comment: You are introducing bias by using modulo (`%`). It would be better to use a [std::uniform_int_distribition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). Also; `rand()` generates pretty poor quality random numbers, a better choice would be [std::mt19937](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) and as for seeding, better use [std::random_device](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) .

Comment: While @ArkadyGodlin intended to explain only, you actually should prefer the for loop in given case for several reasons: 1. scope of `i` is limited to loop body (as you don't need it afterwards anyway) 2. more compact, condition checking and value modification closely together, so you get better readability.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the indexing start with zero in 'C'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your code:

1. The size of your array is 5, but you access 6 indices (1 to 6), you can avoid this by changing the `<=` to `<` in the condition.
2. The indices of an array in C++ start with 0, but you start with 1. You can fix that if you change each `die[i]` to `die[i-1]` in your code.

Another approach (fixing both problems) would be to initialize `i=0` and go with `while (i < 5)`

Comment: "you can avoid this by change the `<=` to `<` in the condition" (`<` instead of `=`)

Comment: Sure. Fixed. Thanks

Comment: "Another approach" - well, it is this one to be preferred in given case. `die[i-1]` is fine `i`'s raw value yet is needed for another purpose, but that's not the case here...

Comment: Well yeah, if I code this I surely use the second (or most likely a `for` loop), but for learning purpose  the first demonstrate (and solve) the problems as well (or even better)

Comment: @OhadEytan regarding 1. you are wrong here, as he need also to change the while loop value to be <5 and not <6, as his array is of size 5, hence the last valid index is 4 and not 5.

Comment: @OhadEytan oh sorry then, i read them as separate problems. best line is your last line that show the correct solution.

Answer (score 6):

No, a better way to generate uniformly distributed random numbers would be

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
std::uniform_int_distribution<> d6(1, 6); // {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} with equal probability
int die[5];
std::generate(die, die + 5, [&gen, &d6](){ return d6(gen); });
```

If you were generating multiple sets of 5d6, you can re-use the same `gen` rather than re-initialising it each time

Comment: Just wondering, if we need to capture `gen`, why don't we `d6`?

Comment: @Aconcagua because I wasn't paying attention

Comment: at the moment I just do it for learning purposes, so `srand` seems a little easyer and I don't need much more **but** I'll consider implementing that when I get eveything else to work. Thanks

Comment: @BiBo learning to use appropriate tools is better than learning tools that "seem easy". I strongly suggest using `std::generate` if nothing else

Comment: @Caleth while you're right, I don't want to use code that I don't quite understand. as soon I have the basics down, I'll look into that, I still need to learn the syntax a little better because I learned Java before.

Answer (score 3):

As others pointed out. Your error stems from using a too small array. This post will be more about your code being more like C.

It is more idiomatic in C++ to use `std::array` instead of raw arrays.

Also it is recommended not to use `rand()` since it produces bad random numbers and by using the modulo operation you are introducing additional bias to you random numbers. Instead one should use the classes from the `<random>` header.

To make the code even more readable you could try to use the functions from the `<algorithm>` to replace you loops by named algorithms.

This leads to following code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>

void dice() {
  std::array<int, 6> die;
  std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dice_roll{1, 6};
  std::generate(begin(die), end(die), [&] { return dice_roll(gen); }); 
  std::copy(begin(die), end(die), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout});
}

int main() {
  dice();
  std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: good, but just a general question for my understanding of c++ : why can you in this case use e.g. `begin` and don't have to type `std::begin`?

Comment: @JHBonarius `die` pulls names in `std::` into consideration because it is a `std::array`. This is called [Argument Dependant Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

Comment: @JHBonarius: When a object `x` is defined in some namespace `a` and a function `f` is applied on it `f(x)` then the compiler will search for `f` both in the global namespace and in `a`. As @Caleth wrote, this is called Argument Dependent Lookup.

Answer (score 0):

index `i` should be from `0` to `5`, not `1` to `6`.
It's obvious that when `i = 6`, it run out of the range of `dice`  which made an error.

Edit these lines:

```
int i = 0;
    while (i <= 5) {
        ....
```

Comment: `int die[5];` -> index 5 is out of range, too!

Comment: @Aconcagua you're right. My mistake. should change dice[6] too

Answer (score -2):

Try this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void populateArray( int ar[], /*const*/ int n )
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i ) ar[i] = std::rand() % 50 + 1 ;
}

int main()
{
    // http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand
    std::srand( std::time(nullptr) ) ; // **** important ****

    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 50;
    int ar[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0} ;

    populateArray( ar, ARRAY_SIZE ) ;

    for( int v : ar ) std::cout << v << ' ' ;
}
```