# Vector subscript out of range while read vector

Tags: c++

I get crash when I try to run this program and error is Expression: vector subscriptout of range. What's the problem?

```
std::vector<DepositCustomers> Deposits; //depositcustomers is a class
std::ifstream fin("in.txt");
int contor = 1;
while (!fin.eof())
{
    Deposits.resize(contor);
    fin >> Deposits[contor];
    contor++;
}
```

I've tried without resize and is the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried using the `push_back(...)` method to add elements?

Comment: Look what [`resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the indexing start with zero in 'C'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

If you resize the vector to size `1`, then there is only room for 1 item in the vector. Since vectors use 0-based indexes, this item is at index `0`. So, when you try to place something at index `1`, it fails with the observed error.

To make the code work, you can make the following change :

```
fin >> Deposits[contor - 1];
```

Or probably better yet, use [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to save yourself the hassle of having to resize.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that vectors, like arrays, are zero-indexed - if you have `k` elements, they are indexed from `0` to `k - 1`.
Thus, `Deposits[contor]` is out of range for the vector, since it has `contor` elements.
(You're lucky that you built a debug version that checks the indexing and found out quickly.)

You could fix this by writing `Deposits[contor-1]`, but you have another issue.

That issue is that you're using `.eof()` as a loop condition.
`eof()` does not mean what you think it means, and you will store one element too many.
(See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for details.)

The "default" C++ input loop looks like

```
std::vector<DepositCustomers> Deposits;
std::ifstream fin("in.txt");
DepositCustomers customer;
while (fin >> customer)
{
    Deposits.push_back(customer);
}
```

And a loop-free version is

```
std::vector<DepositCustomers> Deposits;
std::ifstream fin("in.txt");
using iterator = std::istream_iterator<DepositCustomers>;
std::copy(iterator(fin), iterator(), std::back_inserter(Deposits));
```