# Why do arrays start on 0 instead of 1? (C, C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, array-indexing

Not really a code problem but a doubt, why do arrays on C and C++ start on 0? Does it have anything to do with some internal process?

```
int array[4]={1,2,3,4};
cout<<array[0];
cout<<array[1];
cout<<array[2];
cout<<array[3]; ///This prints 1234
```

But why that instead of

```
int array[4]={1,2,3,4};
cout<<array[1]; //as the first element
cout<<array[2];
cout<<array[3];
cout<<array[4];
```

?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c

Comment: Have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering

Comment: It's syntactic sugar. 'array' is this context is effectively just a memory address. The first element is therefore (array + 0), or array[0]. The second is (array + 1), etc, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Because the notation does pointer arithmetic. `array[0]` actually means *the location of the array plus the size of 0 elements*.

As always in C, you're working close to the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Consider int arr[i] elements.

arr[i] is interpreted as *(arr + i). Now, arr is the address of the array or address of the 0th index element of the array. So, address of next element in the array is arr + 1 (because elements in the array are stored in consecutive memory locations).
So if you do *(arr+0) it gives the starting memory location of the array.
and *(arr+1) gives next memory location. so this **i** i.e 0,1,..etc can use like offset.

As @ravnsgaard said in C, you're working close to the hardware.