# The SIGSEGV error in Qt while looping music

Tags: qt

i'm trying to loop the background music and i always got this SIGSEGV problem that crashed my program. If i remove the QMediaPlaylist playback mode then the program ran just fine.

Here the github link: https://github.com/KhanhSonPham/simplePlaneShooting

```
QMediaPlaylist * playlist = new QMediaPlaylist();
playlist->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::CurrentItemInLoop);
playlist->addMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/engine.mp3"));
playlist->setCurrentIndex(1);


sound = new QMediaPlayer();
sound->setPlaylist(playlist);
sound->play();
```

error output

[image]

Comment: You can add your error output for clarify your question.

Comment: hi, i'm just added a picture for the debugg process

Answer (score 0):

This line of code should change to

`playlist->setCurrentIndex(0);`

Actually you have one item in your playlist. So, it should be on index 0.
I assume that it's a typo but for some information about why C/C++ or many other programming languages use zero-based indices [I refer you here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c).

Comment: Hi, it actually happened with or without the set index function. I know this is wrong but it probably not what caused the error cause the program should have crashed the moment i turned it on

Comment: @SonPham, please try to move the call to```playlist->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::CurrentItemInLoop)``` after calling ```sound->play();```

Comment: here is what i  did, i created a slot, which is play, in there i play the mediaplayer
then set the loop and the program crash immediately..


Audio::Audio(QObject *parent):QMediaPlayer(parent)
{
    playlist = new QMediaPlaylist();
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/engine.mp3"));
    setPlaylist(playlist);
}

void Audio::play()
{
    play();
    playlist->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::Loop);
}

Comment: I have update the code to git up, every thing is in audio.cpp, can u check it out. I have been finding the solution for entire afternoon now....