# Adding two arrays using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to add two arrays. Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
float x[2], y[2];
x[1]=1;
x[2]=2;
y[1]=2;
y[2]=1;
float* end=x+2; // n is the size of the array x
float* p;
float* q; //Given to arrays x and y.


for(p=x,q=y; q,p<end;q++,p++){
        printf("%f",*p+*q );

}
```

Why does this not work. I only get the first value of new array.
Result should be:

```
3
3
```

Comment: Have a look at the comma operator in your loop.What are you doing with `q`?

Comment: If everything else was correct, this code should work even if the for loop should be `for(p=x,q=y; p<end;q++,p++){...` (`q,` is useless even if harmless). Without a true [mcve], we cannot help.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: I have to arrays x and y of the same length and want to add them. If q is usless, then I onyl iterate over array x?

Comment: I added a small example.

Comment: In the condition of the loop (`q,p<end`) the `q,` part doesn't actually do anything, because the result of the comma operator has the type and value of its second operand. What were you actually trying to achieve with this condition?

Comment: After defining an array with two elements (`float x[2];`) the two elements are `x[0]` and `x[1]`. The "thing" `x[2]` does not exist.

Comment: In your question, you already describe the _expected_ output you want. But what is the _actual_ output? That's a generally useful thing to mention.

Comment: @P__J__ Doesn't the given code look remarkably like the code from an exercise?

Comment: so he need to reread the "arrays" chapter

Comment: @P__J__ Dependent upon the author and the book itself, maybe the book is low quality or they made a mistake, so that it is not *her* fault in particular. A sign for that would also be the redundant placed `q` inside of the condition. We just don't know.

Comment: Sorry for this terrible mistake. I know that the indexing starts at 0:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float x[2], y[2];
```

`x` and `y` are both arrays of 2 elements of type `float`.

When using `x[2] = 2;` and `y[2] = 1;`, you attempt to write the values into a third element (which does not exist) beyond the bounds of the arrays which invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) since subscript indexing starts at `0`, not `1`.

For the reason why you can take a look at here:

- [Why does the indexing start with zero in 'C'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c)

Use:

```
x[0] = 1;
x[1] = 2;
y[0] = 2;
y[1] = 1;
```

instead.

---

Example ([Online](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtag1egAyeWpgByegEaZiIAEydSAB1TTCS2pp37Bbj0U6U3MrXVt7Jxk5TAUvBgJmYgIfPQNnWXkg2gSkghDLGztHDMTk1L9SvIKwiJKAShlUbWJkDgByAFIHAGYzZB0sAGpOnvVpAnxUADoEUexOgAYAQSXlswIh3WYzIYgAN1Q8dHq1zoB2ACE1oduhqlZUZk2AD06AVkuHD4ARUiGAJ4fL6/UbXFY3O5vT6LX4jHo/IacMGQ27Qy7I96I0aI749cHLO6A4GwrHw3EolZEoGfTHYhFIymrKl3B5PAgAKiGRhxbwcIPxQwA9EKhrQhnhpEMCAhMEMPAAvOWoKjS2VDJLEZgAoZvFm3NnPLkuJlEw2coYARzBwqFAHE8PtVNLUBriFqAVKXhq1IDpmcIfr7iQ9i5ybr/pbw0DBWHRupuWobdb%2Bd1Lv8Tan%2BacrqiiUMXMQNlQIN1vg53tMHFQPupaGX/hy4/yhhzLad8XmLtiIecfmt2o1WCB2u92qQDO1FuPUCOE9Jmq05d0epxxwQR9P6o0ANYgHoOaYANgc50473OAE4j5xFkfL5xzkIR9xx5Pp6RZ%2B1x9IQItSBuU6DqQcCwDAiAoKguguHg7BkBQEBoNBsHFMgwCXg4pBULBBB2L%2BEDWJu47WGYSQAiOa6kEhuiqAQADytCsORQGkFg2yiOwRGsXgxCxIoTq/ixmAvLE2i4VxGxyFxrB4NYWrEACmhYBR65FroKmNDQ9BMGwHA8PwgjCKIIASGIUgydYv6wLQzA0Sg0jvP%2BTr2O0D5bo0qAuNkgkALQAOpsKwQz%2BcJBBasFfkuJg6AiIoyARbQqA%2BdotDaLI6A%2BfsSR4Mw1jsD%2BMRxMoEBGBU6SkEYNRFPYzgBJ4dBlf47j1bQVXhMUGSFdkuTlFoaSCJkfHxGU%2BRmIU7U1TII2NVUyRtXUnCNAuLRtFwQ4jmOE5cV%2BLwABxHj5R7cEMwDIPFl5VnsuCECGK7OEMmjIXBIy9ItD3rkR26kHujnPu0r6kOpv3vjOI4/n%2BAGfSB4EQEgzQEC4YnkJQSEwXBhj4EQk1aYwLCcfpADuWouBpf2bSDn4jndQwE4QCC6vth3Had51Vh9QFfbKzBYPYEC7lwiz/sO/3jkD/4U1%2B4P/oB7nffulYXkeq67dwPQ9OcPTcNwu3vH9PRvttYOQxz0PwKBEGoyh8Eo1BaOoQMIjALegtYTheGUIRLEkTZCkqVRUE0fQDFMVxbGO5xLH4LxcQCVxwmieJLGScLH4WfJikYB0lFhXg6ntGuml0LjulcLwAiYUZ4iSEIslWXzn5eV4vkBawQX%2BYlyWpelmXZbl%2BXRFkXgqGoM0VWo80da4zXZKPdXZBPk2DUVOTTX1lQD0NdA9aNoTVQNq%2B%2BOVEzVGNtQdUti6rYtZMGyxO2M0dQwO6ISKLNMb%2BLFdmO3a9/yPXbxAXoHnqO9Y2ss9xq2mGraBMDYF/QBmLLad8ja/mllDc2sMQDw0RgQZGiFbZW0cBVb%2B2Mi46XxrwImzASb52AsLcmhsui9AcDTOmDMDqP2fsAV%2B7937s1llzHmlB1oi0BiAYGjCpZgMHPzVc0wrxHneL0I8ix3icGvJrXWwt9ZII/JLaRX1hYOFvnoo2MsZGkGch4ZQ3AgA%3D)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float x[2], y[2];

    x[0] = 1;
    x[1] = 2;
    y[0] = 2;
    y[1] = 1;

    float* end = x + 2; // n is the size of the array x
    float* p;
    float* q; //Given to arrays x and y.


    for (p = x, q = y ; p < end ; q++, p++) {
        printf("%.2f\n", *p + *q);
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
3.00
3.00
```

---

Side Notes:

- > "*I want to add two arrays.*"

  Something like that is not possible. In fact, You do not add the arrays; you don't even add certain elements of it. You only add the values of specific elements as argument in the call to `printf()`. The difference is important.
- `q,` in the `for` loop condition `q,p < end` has no effect. The expression has the value and type of the right hand operand of the comma operator.
- Please learn how to format/indent your code properly. It will help you and other readers of your code in the future.
- Good and free C starting books are [Modern C](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) or [The C Programming Language (2nd Edition)](https://kremlin.cc/k&r.pdf). These and others you can find here:

  [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Hey, I've got a question. Can you please tell me why index of any array starts with 0?

Comment: @Lucas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: Thank you for your answer. Of course the array start with index 0. Sorry for that. While you iterate through the array, the termiantion condition depends only on x. Since I consider two arrays of the same type, I can state, that the end of pointer p is the end of pointer q?

Comment: @Sarah "*While you iterate through the array, the termination condition depends only on `x`.*" - Yes, but it is no problem in this case since the arrays `x` and `y` have equivalent length and we compare `p` to the address on past the array `x`, stored in `end`. --- "*Since I consider two arrays of the same type, I can state, that the end of pointer `p` is the end of pointer `q`?*" - No. `p` and `q` point to different array objects in memory and with that to different addresses. After the `for` loop, they both point one past the relative array, but not to the same location.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I read the [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c) and I came to know that this happens for the simplicity of addressing memory location, which makes sense with what I already know about _Digital Electronics_. But there are other languages like `AWK, Fortran, Lua, R, etc.`, which don't follow this convention. May I ask why?

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it:)

Comment: @Lucas I guess you have to ask the inventors of a specific language of the reason of this made choice particularly. A few links which might be helpful for you, too regarding this concern: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-array-indexes-start-with-0-zero-in-many-programming-languages and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm

Comment: So, It's just a biased decision of the inventors?

Comment: @Lucas "Biased" is maybe not the correct word, since the index starting at 0 is really helpful and beneficial, but in fact, yes. Everything is more or less up to the inventor(s) and at some point you have to make a decision, even if it is one you later regret. It is the same like develop a car f.e. The car's purpose is to bring you from A to B. If the car has 3 or 4 wheels is irrelevant for this, although 4 wheels give you better posture in curves.

Comment: I read the _Quora's_ post about this and quoting a line from **Anders Kaseorg's** answer: _"Zero-based indexing actually simplifies array-related math for the programmer, and simpler math leads to fewer bugs."_ I get it. At the end every answer points to this [why numbering should start at zero?](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html).

Comment: I will not bother you much. Thanks for the replies and yes, for the **CAR's** example too. @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I gotta ask the inventors of `C` or `R`, if I can find'em. :-)