# this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;

Tags: c#

So the code is:

```cs
this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;
```

problem         Message "Index was outside the bounds of the array."    string

[image]

Comment: Do you in fact have a second screen?

Answer (score 0):

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

[Arrays start at zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c/7320709#7320709).

Change your code to this

```cs
this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Location;
```